# how to change font color if row show absent result

Tags: php, fonts

how to change font color if row show absent result then

how to change font color of the row if row show absent 
how can i do this please help me to fix this issue thanks

this the code

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where date '2013-4-30'  order by date ASC");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
            {   


            // echo out the contents of each row into a table

       echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>' . $row['teacherid'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['attendance'] . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
```

and this is the result of this code

```
-------------------------------------------
Teacher Id | Name  | Date     |Attendance |
--------------------------------------------
919        | Abcd  |2013-4-30 |present
918        | xyz   |2013-4-30 |absent 
815        | 123   |2013-4-30 |present
-------------------------------------------
```

i want change absent text color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
echo "<tr>";
```

With

```
echo '<tr class="'.$row['attendance'].'">';
```

Then in your CSS you can do

```
.present { color: green; }
.absent { color: red; }
```

If you just wanted the attendance cell to change colour, you can put the class on the `<td>` rather than the `<tr>`.

**Edit:**

Full version of code as requested.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where date '2013-4-30'  order by date ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        {   


        // echo out the contents of each row into a table

   echo '<tr class="'.$row['attendance'].'">';
        echo '<td>' . $row['teacherid'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['attendance'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
```

If you don't yet have a stylesheet then just put this on your page in the HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .present { color: green; }
    .absent { color: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: yeah this way you could change the background for the row as well as the cell, good alternative +1

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer to include all of your code.